# using ios::clear() with cin

Tags: c++, cin

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[4];

    for(int I = 0; I != 4; ++i) {
        std::cin >> arr[i];

        if(std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cin.clear();
            --i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (auto u : arr)
        std::cout << u << '\n';
}
```

I don't understand why this code is not working. I would like to `std::cin` again the element of `arr` in case `std::cin.fail()` returns true.

Comment: If you want to read again, then why do you `break` out of the loop?

Comment: So that it will run again the for loop with the same value of `i`. I wanted to `break` because if `cin.fail()` will return true again, I will have the chance to `cin` another time. I wanted it to run until I would have give it a number instead of a character for example

Comment: @Tony You don't need the `break`. It will exit the `for` loop.

Comment: Yes I understand now my mistake. Shall I use `continue` or is it the same than writing nothing instead of `break`?

Comment: Since it's going to be the last statement, `continue;` would have the same effect as simply letting the control reach the loop's closing brace. Anyway, once you are past this problem, you'll encounter another one: the "bad" character that caused parsing to fail is still in the stream, so you'll read it right back and fail again. See also [`basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore)

Answer (score 0):

`break` will terminate the loop. That's not what you want.

Note also that you don't remove the offending character from the stream, so your next problem will be an infinite loop.

However even if you remove the offending character, you may get into an infinite loop because there might simply not be four valid integers in the input stream.

Here's a solution that simply does the updating of `i` in the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int arr[4];

  for(int i = 0; i != 4; /* this field intentionally left empty */)
  {
    std::cin >> arr[i];

    if(std::cin) // did the read succeed?
    {
      ++i; // then read the next value
    }
    else
    {
      if (std::cin.eof()) // if we've hit EOF, no integers can follow
      {
        std::cerr << "Sorry, could not read four integer values.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE; // give up
      }
      std::cin.clear();
      std::cin.ignore(); // otherwise ignore the next character and retry
    }
  }

  for (auto u : arr)
    std::cout << u << '\n';
}
```

But the whole thing gets brittle, and input may be interpreted differently than the user intended. Better to just give up if encountering invalid input:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  int arr[4];

  for (auto& u: arr)
    std::cin >> u;

  if (!std::cin) // Did reading the four values fail?
  {
    std::cerr << "Sorry, could not read four integer values.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  for (auto u: arr)
    std::cout << u << "\n";
}
```